# C# Unmanaged Export not working

Tags: c#, .net, dll, dllexport, unmanagedexports

I am trying to get the [Unmanaged Export](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports) Basic sample working.

The steps I am following:

- Create a new classlibrary project.
- Add the UnmanagedExports with
  nuget.
- Change CPU target to x86.
- Add the code from the tutorial I am following to the .cs file.
- Build

The project is built sucesfully, but when I inspect my dll with [DLL Export Viewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html) I can not see any of my functions.

I am using 32 bits OS and SharpDevelop 4.4 (I also have tried with other SharpDevelop versions and with 64bits OS with the same result).

My sln file:

```
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "test", "test\test.csproj", "{AFAA816C-65B2-4B58-9FB2-EB7482AA0F5F}"
    EndProject
    Global
        GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
            Debug|x86 = Debug|x86
            Release|x86 = Release|x86
        EndGlobalSection
        GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
            {AFAA816C-65B2-4B58-9FB2-EB7482AA0F5F}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|x86
            {AFAA816C-65B2-4B58-9FB2-EB7482AA0F5F}.Debug|x86.Build.0 = Debug|x86
            {AFAA816C-65B2-4B58-9FB2-EB7482AA0F5F}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|x86
            {AFAA816C-65B2-4B58-9FB2-EB7482AA0F5F}.Release|x86.Build.0 = Release|x86
        EndGlobalSection
    EndGlobal
```

My csproj file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="Build">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectGuid>{AFAA816C-65B2-4B58-9FB2-EB7482AA0F5F}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>test</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>test</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v2.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'x86' ">
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DebugSymbols>True</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>Full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>False</Optimize>
    <CheckForOverflowUnderflow>True</CheckForOverflowUnderflow>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DebugSymbols>False</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>None</DebugType>
    <Optimize>True</Optimize>
    <CheckForOverflowUnderflow>False</CheckForOverflowUnderflow>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="RGiesecke.DllExport.Metadata">
      <HintPath>..\packages\UnmanagedExports.1.2.7\lib\net\RGiesecke.DllExport.Metadata.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="MyClass.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="packages.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

My cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using RGiesecke.DllExport;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Testme
{
    class Test
    {
        [DllExport("Add", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static int Add(int left, int right)
        {
            return left + right;
        }
........
```

Dll Export Viewer of my dll
[image: DLL export viewer of my dll]

Dll Export Viewer of a working dll (downloaded from the tutorial web)
[image: Dll Export Viewer of a working dll (downloaded from the tutorial web)]

Both dlls (mine and the downloaded) have the same size for my OS but not for the DLL Export Viewer.

What I am missing??

Comment: The tool has a nasty habit of just doing nothing.  Be sure to run VS elevated before adding the Nuget package so its post-build event can be updated.  And you must select a specific target architecture, Project > Properties > Build tab > Target platform setting.

Comment: But I am not using VS. I am using SharpDevelop 4.4. And I am running it elevated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it this way,
You need add the follow line below this line csproj file

```
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />

  <!-- Remove this comment and insert This line-->
  <Import Project="packages/UnmanagedExports.1.2.7/tools/RGiesecke.DllExport.targets" Condition="Exists('packages/UnmanagedExports.1.2.7/tools/RGiesecke.DllExport.targets')"/>
```

Check file exist in your folder "packages/UnmanagedExports.1.2.7/tools/RGiesecke.DllExport.targets"